# linq expression with where any

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have model

```
public class MyModel
{
   public List<Car>Cars {get; set;}
   public int? SomeId {get; set;}
   ...     
}
public class Car
{
   ...
   public int? FormatId {get; set;}  
}
```

inside linq expression I want to fetch list of MyModel objects which has Cars with FormatId equal to SomeId inside MyModel

```
var q = model.Cars.Where(x=>x.FormatId.HasValue && x.FormatId == model.SomeId)
.how to select here?);
```

Comment: You already seem to have it: `var q = model.Cars.Where(x=>x.FormatId.HasValue && x.FormatId == model.SomeId);`

Comment: If you want a List, just add .ToList()

Comment: *I want to fetch list of MyModel objects*: Where is your list of models?  From your code, you only have a single model as your starting point.  The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: You can simply add a ToList() part at the end of your linq query, or a ToArray() if you prefer array

Answer (score 2):

Well, if want to get `List<Car>` add `ToList()` to your existing query or assuming you have list of `MyModel` with name `myModelsList`, you can do :

```
List<MyModel> mm = myModelsList.Where(m => 
                     m.Cars.Any(x => FormatId.HasValue && x.FormatId == model.SomeId))
                       .ToList();
```